# Configuring Key-bindings from Org-Table

Tags: key-bindings, org-babel, org-table, literate-programming, configuration-files

I use `init.org` file to configure my emacs, and then tangle it into `init.el`.

Now, I would like to configure my keybindings from org-table (for more readable and printable).

Basically, I'd like to only maintain the table(s) (e.g. `table_keybindings` in the below) to configure my *never-ending* configuration of my keybindings. At the same time then  I'll get beautifully latex-printed table for my wife to follow.

**Question**: So how to convert `table_keybindings` table into `(garids-keybind/for-all-modes ... )`?

(I've previously used org-table as a variable (e.g. `:var x=table_keybindings`) into python source-blocks, However in elips I just can't grasp it.)

[image]

```org
*** general
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(use-package general
  :config (general-evil-setup t)

  ;; Keybindings for everywhere
  (general-create-definer garids-keybind/for-all-modes
    :keymaps  '(normal visual emacs)
    :prefix         "SPC"
    :global-prefix  "C-SPC")

  ;; Keybindings inside Org-mode-map
  (general-create-definer garids-keybind/in-org-mode
    :states '(normal visual)
    :keymaps '(org-mode-map)
    :prefix        "SPC"
    :global-prefix "C-SPC")
  )
#+end_src
*** keybinds for all modes
#+name: table_keybindings
| key(s) | function                 | short description |
|--------+--------------------------+-------------------|
| ~SPC~  | execute-extended-command | M-x               |
| ~d~    | dired-jump               | (d)ired           |
| ~f~    | find-file                | (f)ind-file       |


#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(garids-keybind/for-all-modes
  "SPC" '(execute-extended-command              :which-key "M-x"                   )
  "d"   '(dired-jump                            :which-key "(d)ired"               )
  "f"   '(find-file                             :which-key "(f)ind-file"           )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How tables are passed to Emacs Lisp code blocks

Here's a toy example table with column headers, an `hline` separating the headers from the body and cells that contain strings - very much like the table in the OP's example, except for the deliberate simplicity of the cell contents:

```org
#+name: foo
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
|-------+-------+-------|
| a     | b     | c     |
| d     | e     | f     |
| g     | h     | i     |
```

Here's an elisp block that gets the table above passed as the argument `tab`. The body of
the block just evaluates the argument. Note that we ask for the results (i.e. the value of `tab`)
as uninterpreted output (usually that is done with `:results raw` but I find that using `:results drawer`
is clearer):

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer :var tab=foo
  tab
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
((a b c) (d e f) (g h i))
:end:
```

A couple of observations:

- the column header is not part of the results and neither is the
  hline separator (see the `:colnames` header if you want it
  included, but in this case, we don't care about the column
  headers).
- the results show that the table is interpreted as a list of rows.
- each row is a list of elements, one for each column.
- each element is a string<sup>[1]</sup> (this is not quite clear from the output:
  Org Babel prints strings out without the enclosing double quotes but if
  you ask whether some element, say the third<sup>[2]</sup> element of the second row is a string, the answer is "yes":

```el
   #+begin_src elisp  :results drawer :var tab=foo
     (stringp (nth 2 (nth 1 tab)))
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS:
   :results:
   t
   :end:
```

### String transformations

We now can look at the OP's table:

```org
#+name: table_keybindings
| key(s) | function                 | short description |
|--------+--------------------------+-------------------|
| ~SPC~  | execute-extended-command | M-x               |
| ~d~    | dired-jump               | (d)ired           |
| ~f~    | find-file                | (f)ind-file       |
```

The basic transformation needed for each row is

```
<key>, <function>, <short description> ---> "<modified key>" '(<function> :which-key "<short description>")
```

where the modified key just loses the verbatim markers in the original
key, whereas the function name and the short description are
unmodified. This is a simple string transformation. Here's a small
example block that takes just the first row of the table and does the
transformation:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer :var row=table_keybindings[2]
  (format "  \"%s\" '(%s :which-key \"%s\")" (string-trim (nth 0 row) "~" "~") (nth 1 row) (nth 2 row))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
  "SPC" '(execute-extended-command :which-key "M-x")
:end:
```

We then have to repeat the above for each row. We use a mapping function over the rows and produce a string as a result:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer :var tab=table_keybindings
  (mapconcat (lambda (row)   (format "  \"%s\" '(%s :which-key \"%s\")" (string-trim (nth 0 row) "~" "~") (nth 1 row) (nth 2 row)))
              tab "\n")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
  "SPC" '(execute-extended-command :which-key "M-x")
  "d" '(dired-jump :which-key "(d)ired")
  "f" '(find-file :which-key "(f)ind-file")
:end:
```

All we have to do now is wrap this in the `garids-keybind/for-all-modes` call to produce the final version of the keybinder:

```el
#+name: keybinder
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer :var tab=table_keybindings
  (concat "(garids-keybind/for-all-modes" "\n"
          (mapconcat (lambda (row)   (format "  \"%s\" '(%s :which-key \"%s\")" (string-trim (nth 0 row) "~" "~") (nth 1 row) (nth 2 row)))
                     tab "\n")
          "\n)")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: keybinder
:results:
(garids-keybind/for-all-modes
  "SPC" '(execute-extended-command :which-key "M-x")
  "d" '(dired-jump :which-key "(d)ired")
  "f" '(find-file :which-key "(f)ind-file")
)
:end:
```

Note that we named this result block, so we can call it by name. Note also that all this block does is produce
a string: the string looks like Lisp code, but it's still just a string.

### Evaluating the string as code

We now have a (named) block that produces the required code as a string. But the string represents a Lisp program
and what we want to do is run that program! We can do that with `eval`: we convert the string into a Lisp
data structure using `read` and then pass that data structure to `eval`. This is (part of) the magic of Lisp.

```el
#+name: runner
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer :var prog=keybinder
  (eval (read prog))
#+end_src
```

What this does is call the `keybinder` block to produce the program as a string and initialize the `prog` parameter with that string. We then call `read` on it to convert it to a Lisp data structure which is then passed to `eval` for evaluation.

I don't show the results here because I don't have the `general` package installed and so I can't define `garids-keybind/for-all-modes` (and I certainly don't want to debug it! If that's necessary, that would be fodder
for another question).

### Summary

The only things you need are: a) your table `table_keybindings`, b)
the block named `keybinder` above and c) the block named `runner`.
When you run the `runner` block, it needs to initialize its `prog`
parameter, so it runs the `keybinder` block and initializes `prog` to
be the resulting string. `runner` then calls `read` on that string to
convert it into a Lisp data structure which is then passed to `eval`
for evaluation.

---

##### Footnotes

[1] Exception: if the contents of a cell look like a number, then the type of element in the resulting list is numeric, not string. But neither the toy table above, nor the table of the OP's example have cell contents that look like numbers.

[2] Recall that `nth` counts from zero, so `(nth 2 ...)` gets the *third* item of the list. Similarly `(nth 1 ...)` gets the *second* item.

Comment: Thank you as always !!! Great explanation about using org-tables in elisp. I will most definetly revisit this answer in the future when I work with org-tables on other things.

Comment: Since I tangle `init.org` to `init.el`, I don't have to evaluating `runner` src-block, (I just need tangle the result of `keybinder`). Therefore, I'm going to modify `keybinder` block's header into `#+begin_src elisp :var tab=table_keybindings :wrap src emacs-lisp :tangle no` to wrap it's result in elisp (via `wrap ...`) and don't tangle itself into `init.el` (via `:tangle no`). Thanks !!!

Comment: Yes, you are right: you write the program in a different file and when that file is loaded, it goes through `read-eval` so you don't have to do it manually. But when you are testing things, it's still nice to be able to run small snippets all the way through the flow.